# Django Weasyprint PDF output into Postgres Database

Tags: python, django, pdf, weasyprint

I am trying to stick a WeasyPrint html PDF into the Model.  Using Django.

I can generate the PDF file fine.

```
pdf_file = HTML(string=html,base_url=base_url).write_pdf(stylesheets, [css_path],font_config=font_config)
```

Now what is best way to convert the pdf_file output to a format I can use for the database?

```
class Reports(models.Model):

    pdf = models.FileField( upload_to='media/pdfs/', max_length=254, )

    created = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

If I do something like this it creates the file automatically before the Model.

```
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    report = fs.save(f'pdfs/{uuid}.pdf', File(BytesIO(pdf_file)) )
```

And gives the table a 'pdf/...' in the database.

What is most efficent way to convert the Wesasy HTML into a format the Model can use and let the model save the file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two steps:

1. create the object without the file assigned (making sure that `file` field is nullable, you can handle validation separately if needed).
2. Use `save` method on the `file` field to save the pdf

Here's how you can do it:

```
import io
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile, File

res = io.BytesIO()
HTML(string=html).write_pdf(res)
pdf = ContentFile(res.getvalue())

report = Reports.objects.create(
    ...
)
report.file.save(filename, File(pdf))
```

`filename` is the file name you can generate however

Comment: that is sort of what i origanaly had.  i was thinking i could put the file inside the Reports.objects.create().  Oh well, if it works - it works.  Thanks.

Comment: sure, I was struggling with the same issue (also the fact I wanted to define my own file name), it's is something that I've been using and is working fine.